# What is the time complexity of heapifyUp() method?

Tags: data-structures, heap, priority-queue, heapsort, binary-heap

I have seen a few implementation of heaps that use heapifyUp() and 
heapifyDown() methods. Couldn't we implement heapifyUp() using the heapifyDown() as :

```
 for( int i = heap_size/2; i >= 0; i--)
   heapifyDown(i);
```

I beleive the time complexity of the above code snippet is O(n) (according to Cormen).

Now the heapifyUp() implementation was as follows:

```
 while(i!=0 && arr[parent(i)]>arr[i])
 {
      swap(arr[i],arr[parent(i)]);
      i = parent(i);
 }
```

Now if i am not wrong the timeplexity of the above implementation is O(logn)

Now since O(logn) is better than O(n) the heapifyUp() method certainly done better. So why does Cormen use the bottom-up heapify (method 1) to build heaps??

Please correct me if I am wrong and which implementation is better?

Comment: Can you give a link to the Cormen paper you are referencing. Are talking specifically about what happens after a value is added when building a heap?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your two code snippets are doing two entirely different things. The code that does the `heapifyDown()` is rearranging an entire array into a heap. It's moving half of the elements in the array, and the time complexity is only O(n) for the entire process.

The `heapifyUp()` code that you post is moving a single element up the heap. Its time complexity is O(log n). If you were to use that method to build a heap from an array, the total time complexity would be O(n log n).

`heapifyUp()` and `heapifyDown()` are used for two different things, and there's a reason for each use.

`heapifyUp()` is called when inserting items into the heap. When inserting an item, it is placed at the end of the heap and then filtered up through the heap. The worst case is O(log n). The average case is much different. On average, half the time the item won't have to move because it belongs on the bottom row. One-fourth of the time it will only have to move one level up. One-eighth of the time it will only have to move two levels, etc.

`heapifyDown()` is used when removing the minimum element. We move the last item from the heap to the root, and then move it down through the heap to its proper place. When moving down from the top, heapifyDown() has a worst case of O(log n). The average case, also, is O(log n).

The loop you posted is a second, special, use of `heapifyDown()`:

```
for( int i = heap_size/2; i >= 0; i--)
  heapifyDown(i);
```

This is O(n) because it's taking advantage of the heap structure.

First of all, note that it's only moving half of the items. Second, not every item is moving all the way from the top. For example, if we have a heap of 127 items (that'd be a full heap with 7 levels), then 64 of the items are never even examined because they're already at the bottom level. 32 of the items move only one place. 16 of the items move at most 2 levels, etc. You end up with:

```
64*0 + 32*1 + 16*2 + 8*3 + 4*4 + 2*5 + 1*6
0 + 32 + 32 + 24 + 16 + 10 + 6 = 120 swaps
```

A maximum of 120 swaps when creating the heap using the loop.

You *could* use `heapifyDown()` when inserting a new item into the heap, but that would be slower than using `heapifyUp()`, because on average every item inserted would have to move further than if it were inserted from the bottom.